# HC-05 Module AT command mode won't respond

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, at-command, hc-05

I've been trying to connect two HC-05 bluetooth modules together as master and slave devices. I know that to do this i need to establish one as a slave device and one as a master using the AT command mode. I am using an arduino nano with each of the modules and the circuit i have used is shown:

```
Vcc -----> 5V

GND ----> GND

Rx ------> Rx

Tx ------> Tx
```

I followed various online tutorials and have used this code:

```
include SoftwareSerial.h

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(0, 1); // RX | TX

    void setup()
    {
    
      Serial.begin(9600);
    
      BTSerial.begin(9600);  // HC-05 default speed in AT command more
    
      Serial.println("Enter AT commands:");
    
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
     
      // Keep reading from HC-05 and send to Arduino Serial Monitor
      if (BTSerial.available()){
    
        Serial.write(BTSerial.read());
    
      }
    
      // Keep reading from Arduino Serial Monitor and send to HC-05
    
      if (Serial.available()){
    
        BTSerial.write(Serial.read());
    
      }
    
    }
```

Using the button on the module or by setting the EN pin high, i am able to put the module into AT mode as displayed by the LED blinking every 2 seconds. However, i receive no response after sending commands to the module using the serial monitor when i should receive a confirmation of my command.

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Comment: UART connection 101: Tx --> Rx, Rx --> Tx.

Comment: I have tried the wires both ways round and using various different sets of pins with no success. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that eventually worked for me: I used this circuit with a voltage divider:

- Vcc -----> 5V
- GND ----> GND
- D2 ------> Tx
- D3 ------> Rx

I ended up having to buy an Uno for this to work, I'm assuming then that my Nano's were faulty in some way. I then used the following code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(2, 3); // RX | TX

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.begin(38400);  // HC-05 default speed in AT command more
  Serial.println("Enter AT commands:");
}

void loop()
{

  // Keep reading from HC-05 and send to Arduino Serial Monitor
  if (BTSerial.available()){
    Serial.write(BTSerial.read());
  }

  // Keep reading from Arduino Serial Monitor and send to HC-05
  if (Serial.available()){
    BTSerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

This allowed me to enter the AT mode and also receive responses.

One of the issues was that I was using the Tx and Rx pins which are also used to communicate with the computer so cannot be used with the HC-05 at the same time.

Another issue was the baudrate: I alternated between 9600 and 38400 for each communication until I found a combination that worked, and adjusted the speed in the *Serial monitor* so that it made sense.

Then I was able to use the command mode normally.

Answer (score 0):

For regular communication it should be next:
Uno RX should be connected to TX of BT05
Uno TX should be connected to RT of BT05

The Reason - they communicate between each other. One is sending info from TX(transmitter) and another should receive it with RX(receiver) and vice versa.

But, with approach abouve, you will need to create virtual second SerialPort and to write simple code to correctly setup BT05 with AT commands. But also, you will don't need to swap wires when you would like to use it.

For setting up BT05 with blank code you can use vice versa connection:
Uno RX should be connected to RT of BT05
Uno TX should be connected to TX of BT05

Vice versa connections of this pins is correct in one case too, but it only suitable if you would like to set it up with blank code directly through Serial Monitor. But, in this case you will need to swap them back.
This connection joins main Serial port of MC that used in communication with PC with also BT05. So be careful to don't use print(), because it can interrupt with BT.